# How can I use a vim plugin for a filetype that the plugin is not intended for?

Tags: python, vim, plugins, jupyter

If you convert a Jupyter Notebook to a markdown document (with pandoc, for example) then it's nice and easy to edit it without having to launch the browser. I enjoy the `vim-markdown` plugin for this work.

I have since found the `jupyter-vim` plugin, which can send python code snippets directly from vim to a jupyter-qtconsole (far more light-weight than the Jupyter notebook). My problem is that vim only activates the `jupyter-vim` plugin for a "python" filetype, so I can't use it when editing a markdown file. But I don't see any reason I shouldn't be able to use the plugin from a markdown file to send the qtconsole code snippets from a fenced python code block, for exampe.

I'm almost sure there's a way to do this, but I have not figured it out. I tried, for example, making a 'markdown' directory in the `~/.vim/bundle/jupyter-vim/ftplugin/` directory. But I'm shooting in the dark. I can't see how to do this in vim help for `:h filetype-plugins`.

Any ideas would be most welcome...!

Answer (score 1):

After looking in `~/.vim/bundle/jupyter-vim/plugin/jupyter.vim`, I found the call I needed that initializes the jupyter plugin.

In vim, with my markdown file open, I just need to `:call jupyter#load#MakeStandardCommands()`.

Now it works -- I essentially have a Jupyter Notebook running in vim!

If you do this you'll probably also want to

````
let g:jupyter_cell_separators = ['```']
````

in `.vimrc`. Then a fenced code block is run like a cell in Jupyter.

Comment: Maybe also try setting multiple filetypes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2604558/2072269